# Is it possible to change scene after tapping a label in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I have a school project to make a game which is going fine, but I'm struggling to add a back button. I had an idea to click on the word back to take you to the menu but I have no idea how to do it. The normal "button" isn't available as it is going back from a sprite kit scene. Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: crap why didn't you tell me this yesterday. I was wondering if you were gonna put a back button in it or not

Comment: @Fluidity I did think about it but I thought you already spent so much time helping me out and didn't want to waste anymore ahaha. I managed to get my deadline moved to Wednesday so if you have time then it would be great if you could help with this :)

Comment: i'm not great with UIKit but I'm sure there is an answer on SO already for this

Comment: if you know how to present your MenuVC I can rig up a SKButton for you :P. And I told you I was bored and had nothing to do yesterday so it's no biggie.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Lol. Somehow I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

## MenuVC.swift:

```
enum gameType {
  case easy
  case wobble
  case player2
}

var currentGameType: gameType = .easy
var navController = UINavigationController()
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard()

func presentMenuVC() {
  let menuVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuVC") as! MenuVC
  navController.pushViewController(menuVC, animated: true)
}

class MenuVC : UIViewController {

    @IBAction func Player2(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .player2)
    }
    @IBAction func Easy(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .easy)
    }
    @IBAction func Wobble(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .wobble)
    }

    func moveToGame(game: gameType) {

      navController = self.navigationController!
      storyBoard = self.storyboard!

      let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController

        currentGameType = game

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)

    }
}
```

## NewFile.swift:

```
class MainMenuButton: SKSpriteNode {

  init(text: String, font: String) {
    let label = SKLabelNode(text: text)
    label.fontName = font

    let texture = SKView().texture(from: label)

    super.init(texture: texture!, color: .clear, size: texture!.size())
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    presentMenuVC()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}
```

## GameScene.swift (add to your didMoveToView func at bottom):

```
addChild(MainMenuButton(text: "go back", font: "Chalkduster"))
```

Comment: I created a file named newFile.swift and copied the code in, however, I have received multiple errors e.g. unresolved identifier, undeclared type. I think I did it wrong.

Comment: i emailed you the project, open that up

Comment: I would not recommend this,  If memory serves correctly, you are just adding a view controller on top of another view controller, and will eventually blow the stack.  I would look into creating segues in the storyboard to handle this kind of stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can add a normal `UIButton` to the `SKView`, but that may not be the cleanest solution. You can instead us the touch functions on `SKLabelNode` like `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. I made a simple implementation of a button for `SpriteKit` this way. You can check it out on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bajtyngier/SKButtonNode).

Comment: he is asking how to get back to his UIKit viewcontroller from an SKScene

Comment: Confusing question then:) Hard to judge without a context, but you can call `present(nil)` on your `SKView` or simply dismiss the controller that this view belongs to. Totally different subject.

Comment: haha, I don't know UIKit very well I guess I always work in SKScene. He has a main.storyboard viewcontroller that he wants to get back to from his SKScene